# Qt: How to create a directory in project file?

Tags: qt, qmake

I just want to crossplatform make a single directory from *.pro file. I use some commands like $(COPY_DIR) and $(COPY_FILE) well. And I saw in internets a many examples with command $(MKDIR) but it did not work for me.

It prints:
C:/Projects/installer/installer.pro(24): Extra characters after test expression.

when I used $$(MKDIR) on line 24.

Or:
C:/Projects/installer/installer.pro(24):  '$' is not a recognized test function.

when I $(MKDIR).

What the proper way to create a directory in qmake projects?

Comment: Please edit the question and add a description of what you're trying to do and the relevant project file fragments. Presumably, you don't wish to copy files while `qmake` itself is running but when the project is built - so far it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Use `QMAKE_MKDIR` like so:

```
mytarget.commands += $${QMAKE_MKDIR} $$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/foo)
```

### Long answer

qmake provides variables holding useful commands. Take a look at [Undocumented QMake](https://wiki.qt.io/Undocumented_QMake#Undocumented_variables) article on Qt Wiki. The one you are looking for is `QMAKE_MKDIR`, but you might also be interested in `QMAKE_CHK_DIR_EXISTS`.

If the values given by qmake do not suite you, you can use the environment to retrieve the mkdir command:

```
$(MKDIR) $$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/foo)
$$(MKDIR) $$shell_path($${OUT_PWD}/foo)
```

The `$(...)` syntax retrieves the environment variable when `make` (or `nmake`...) is run while `$$(...)` retrieves it when `qmake` is run.

Also the mkdir command should be call in the context of a "make target" declared with `QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS`. See [Adding custom targets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) in qmake documentation.

Comment: Thx. It works.
My misstake was that I used $(MKDIR) separate from "mytarget.commands" :)